# is this from padma purana ? reme ramesho vividhaiva priyayā rādhayāsaḥ

Tags: scripture, puranas, mantras, reference-request, padma-purana

Hi I am trying to identify if the below verse is from padma purana

> reme ramesho vividhaiva priyayā rādhayāsaḥ

रेमे रमेशो विविधैव प्रियया राध्यासः

potential meaning for each words

- रेमे (Reme): To be delighted
- रमेशः (Ramesha): Lord of Rama
- विविधैः (Vividhaih): Various, diverse
- प्रियया (Priyaya): Beloved, lover
- राध्यासः (Rādhyāsah): With Radha

any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: While asking about Sanskrit verses provide translations also cause not everybody in this forum understand sanskrit or devnagri.

Comment: @SriShivaCharañamDāsaVishñu thanks for the suggestion.
not 100% sure, have added some meaning based on my limited understanding.